# How to write the following Scala code without vars

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What follows is a simple snippet of code defining a Node class for representing linked lists and a method for adding a node to the end of a list. In the code, there are two vars. How can I write this code without any vars?

```
case class Node[A](data: A, var next: Option[Node[A]])
```

```
def addNodeToEnd[A](node: Node[A], nodeToAdd: Node[A]): Node[A] = {
    if (node.next == None) {
        node.next = Some(nodeToAdd)
    } else {
        var current = node
        while ( current.next != None) {
           current = current.next.getOrElse(current)
        }
        current.next = Some(nodeToAdd)      
    }
    node
}

//Test                              
val node = Node(1, Some(Node(2, Some(Node(3, None)))))
val nodeToAdd = Node(88, None)

println(addNodeToEnd(node, nodeToAdd))
```

Comment: Well, there won't be much point in removing the `vars` in the method _(since local mutation is considered ok for performance and readability)_ since the data structure itself is mutable _(since global mutability is the real problem that immutability tries to solve)_. - But whatever, just use recursion, instead of that `while` just call `addNodeToEnd(node.next, nodeToAdd)`

Comment: If you also want to remove the `var` from the **Node** class, you are basically recreating a **List**, I may give you the code that does an append to a List, but you can find that code in the internet, this is a pretty standard exercise. If you want to learn **Scala** especially FP concepts like immutability, the best would be to solve this problem by yourself, the trick is **recursion**, then **tail-recursion**. However, if you are doing this process by yourself alone it will be hard, I would recommend you to follow some course or book that cover all the concepts step by step.

Comment: Just wanted to see various ways people might approach this.

Comment: As I said **recursion** or **tail-recursion**, [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/29okVA4JS0yGxjuBL340aA/19) you can see both examples.

Comment: Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach. No `var`s. No mutation.

```
case class Node[A](data: A, next: Option[Node[A]])

def addToEnd[A](node: Node[A], toAdd: A): Node[A] =
  node.next.fold(node.copy(next = Some(Node(toAdd,None))))(
            n => node.copy(next = Some(addToEnd(n,toAdd))))

//Test                              
val list = Node(1, Some(Node(2, Some(Node(3, None)))))
addToEnd(list, 88)
//res0: Node[Int] = Node(1,Some(Node(2,Some(Node(3,Some(Node(88,None)))))))
```

Or, if you prefer...

```
def nodeAppend[A](ns: Node[A], toAppnd: Node[A]): Node[A] =
  ns.next.fold(ns.copy(next = Some(toAppnd)))(
        nxt => ns.copy(next = Some(nodeAppend(nxt, toAppnd))))
//Test                              
val list = Node(1, Some(Node(2, None)))
val listToAdd = Node(88, Some(Node(99,None)))

nodeAppend(list, listToAdd)
//res0: Node[Int] = Node(1,Some(Node(2,Some(Node(88,Some(Node(99,None)))))))
```

Comment: Thank you. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @JackWidman please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers